# How do Blade of Disaster and Resilient Sphere interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Does the Blade of Disaster spell, which can "pass through any barrier", have the ability to enter a Resilient Sphere spell - a "barrier" that specifically mentions that other spell effects can't pass through it?

If it can, can the blade do damage to a creature inside in spite of the fact that "a creature or object inside [the sphere] can't be damaged by attacks or effects originating from outside [the sphere]"? The attack would certainly come from within the sphere, but I'm not sure if the spell would be considered an effect that originates from outside the sphere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### It's up to the DM, but I would give the edge to the 9th level spell.

This is a case of two *exception* rules contradicting each other. *Xanathar's Guide* expresses the *specific beats general* rule like so:

> The game also includes elements — class features, spells, magic items, monster abilities, and the like — that sometimes contradict a general rule. When an exception and a general rule disagree, the exception wins.

"Nothing can pass through the barrier" and "the blade can pass through any barrier" are contradictory exception rules. So it is entirely up to the DM how these interact.

I would rule that the 9th level spell "wins" so to speak, over the 4th level spell: *blade of disaster* ignores *resilient sphere*.

Comment: Is there an element of the barrier also counting as total cover in the same way a window does? Preventing the attack being targeted in the first place? I agree in principle with your answer though. Cover may be the wrong word, but blocking direct line to the target, whatever term that is.

Comment: @SeriousBri *blade of disaster* doesn't directly target individuals - its effect is to create a blade which can then be used to attack people - so the rules about a clear line of effect aren't relevant. (At the moment of casting you wouldn't be able to *create* the blade on the far side of any barrier that blocked line of effect, to be sure, but once the blade exists it is explicitly unimpeded by such obstacles.)